# ProgressBar does not stop after subprocess completion

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

Here is my progressbar code to add progress to my subprocess:

```
    ft = ttk.Frame(self.labelframe)
    fb = ttk.Frame(self.labelframe)

    ft.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.TOP)
    fb.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.TOP)

    self.pb_hd = ttk.Progressbar(ft, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate')
    self.pb_hd.pack(expand=False, fill=tk.X, side=tk.TOP)

    cmd = ["adb","pull","/data","/home/User/Project/Internal-Storage"]
    self.proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT )
    self.pb_hd.start()

    while self.proc.poll() is None:
          self.update()

    self.pb_hd.stop()
```

The `pb_hd.stop()` does not seem to work.
And how do I add percentage to the progress bar to let the user know the process completion progress.

Comment: to use `Progressbar` you have to use `root.after` or you have to use `Progressbar` in thread.

Comment: Could you tell me how do I incorporate the root.after for the above code ? I don't have any idea about it. I am just a beginner to Python, trying out certain things. :-|